# Why is the preloaded not vanishing after side has been loaded?

Tags: html, css

Why is the preloaded not vanishing after side has been fully loaded? Like, after the page is loaded. I looked the web, and found this Java script code, apparently not working:

___ edit: I have deutet the s and Name, maybe i have embedded wrong? 
I created a via WP plugin WP coder an embedded code and i put it on top of my front page...

THX

```js
var loading = document.getElementsByClassName('loading');

window.addEventListener ("load", function() {

loading.style.display = 'none';

});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quattrocento+Sans);
.loading {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.loading-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
}
.loading-text span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Quattrocento Sans', sans-serif;
}
.loading-text span:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
          filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 0s infinite linear alternate;
          animation: blur-text 1.5s 0s infinite linear alternate;
}
.loading-text span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
          filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.2s infinite linear alternate;
          animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.2s infinite linear alternate;
}
.loading-text span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
          filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.4s infinite linear alternate;
          animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.4s infinite linear alternate;
}
.loading-text span:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
          filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.6s infinite linear alternate;
          animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.6s infinite linear alternate;
}
.loading-text span:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
          filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.8s infinite linear alternate;
          animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.8s infinite linear alternate;
}
.loading-text span:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
          filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 1s infinite linear alternate;
          animation: blur-text 1.5s 1s infinite linear alternate;
}
.loading-text span:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
          filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 1.2s infinite linear alternate;
          animation: blur-text 1.5s 1.2s infinite linear alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes blur-text {
  0% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
            filter: blur(0px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
            filter: blur(4px);
  }
}

@keyframes blur-text {
  0% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
            filter: blur(0px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
            filter: blur(4px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loading">
  <div class="loading-text">
    <span class="loading-text-words">L</span>
    <span class="loading-text-words">O</span>
    <span class="loading-text-words">A</span>
    <span class="loading-text-words">D</span>
    <span class="loading-text-words">I</span>
    <span class="loading-text-words">N</span>
    <span class="loading-text-words">G</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `getElementByClass` does not exist, it should be `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: hallo, still not working -.-... the page loads, but not disappearing ... THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You needed to use getElementsByClassName, which returns a collection, so to get the specific element you need to use an index, such as loading[0], and for addEventListener the first parameter is the event, which in your case would be "load".

**Update**

I threw in some console logs to explain what is happening.

```js
var loading = document.getElementsByClassName('loading');

window.addEventListener ("load", function() {
    console.log("page fully loaded");
    //Hide the spinner after 2 seconds
    setTimeout(function(){
        loading[0].style.display = 'none';
        console.log("timeout executed");
    }, 2000);
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quattrocento+Sans);
.loading {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.loading-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
}
.loading-text span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Quattrocento Sans', sans-serif;
}
.loading-text span:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
          filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 0s infinite linear alternate;
          animation: blur-text 1.5s 0s infinite linear alternate;
}
.loading-text span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
          filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.2s infinite linear alternate;
          animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.2s infinite linear alternate;
}
.loading-text span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
          filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.4s infinite linear alternate;
          animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.4s infinite linear alternate;
}
.loading-text span:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
          filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.6s infinite linear alternate;
          animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.6s infinite linear alternate;
}
.loading-text span:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
          filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.8s infinite linear alternate;
          animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.8s infinite linear alternate;
}
.loading-text span:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
          filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 1s infinite linear alternate;
          animation: blur-text 1.5s 1s infinite linear alternate;
}
.loading-text span:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
          filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 1.2s infinite linear alternate;
          animation: blur-text 1.5s 1.2s infinite linear alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes blur-text {
  0% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
            filter: blur(0px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
            filter: blur(4px);
  }
}

@keyframes blur-text {
  0% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
            filter: blur(0px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
            filter: blur(4px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loading">
  <div class="loading-text">
    <span class="loading-text-words">L</span>
    <span class="loading-text-words">O</span>
    <span class="loading-text-words">A</span>
    <span class="loading-text-words">D</span>
    <span class="loading-text-words">I</span>
    <span class="loading-text-words">N</span>
    <span class="loading-text-words">G</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I have updated code above, no it should be disappearing after page is loaded, maybe i have embedded wrongly?

Comment: Hallo, thanks now its working w/ the 2 sec delay. just add your provided code to the finished loaded ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm unclear on what you're asking.  What do you want added?

Comment: Hallo, aim just wanting that, after the page is loaded:            window.addEventListener ("load", function() {
    loader.style.display = 'none';
});             I have a WP plugin, where i can put in css, html, JS, and that plugging creates: [WP-Coder id="3"] --> shortcode, what i have added to home-page-front.

Comment: Isn't that what my code is doing?  Or are you trying to find out why it's working in my example but not in your post?  I'm just trying to understand so I can help you properly.

Comment: hey, yours is working fine, with the 2 seconds delay, but now aim figuring out how to set the delay to XYZ after the page is loaded, like 1 seconds after the page is loaded the banner disapears. hope you unterstand :)

Comment: OK, I've been rereading your comments and this is sounding like a separate issue.  You just asked for help with your JavaScript code, which is what I gave you.  I'm pretty unfamiliar with WordPress, so I can't really help you there.  You would need to make a separate post regarding getting this working in WordPress.

Comment: Hallo, the code is fine and working fine on my WP landing page, so no worries. Iam just trying out how to set in JS that the pre Loader is disappearing after the PAGE is fully LOADED and a dedicated time after fully LOADED that the Preloaded is invisible. Example: you enter my homepage -> now the preloaded starts (is already working) -> page is fully loaded -> preloaded still up for 1 second an then -> invisible. Best

Comment: OK, I think I understand what you want and why there is some confusion.  You're wanting the loader to display 1 second after the page is fully loaded, right?  If so, then you basically have that already.  window.addEventListener watching "load" executes after the page is fully loaded.  Then, the setTimeOut will execute the code 2 seconds later (in my example).  I just edited my post so you can watch the console logs to see how it works.  So, all you need to do is change the setTimeOut from 2000 to 1000 and you should be good to go.  Let me know if I'm still not understanding correctly.

Comment: hallo, yes that is what i was looking for :) Thank you